# Uniform sampling from a simplex

Tags: algorithms, randomness, random-number-generator, sampling

I am looking for an algorithm to generate an array of N random numbers, such that the sum of the N numbers is 1, and all numbers lie within 0 and 1. For example, N=3, the random point (x, y, z) should lie within the triangle:

```
x + y + z = 1
0 < x < 1
0 < y < 1
0 < z < 1
```

Ideally I want each point within the area to have equal probability. If it's too hard, I can drop the requirement. Thanks.

Comment: What is the target distribution? What have you tried?

Comment: Note that there is always [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling): sample $n$ uniform numbers and reject if the numbers don't add up to $1$. Here, the expected number of iterations is uncomfortably high, so you should do something else.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let us first assume that you want to sample within

```
x + y + z = 1
0 ≤ x ≤ 1
0 ≤ y ≤ 1
0 ≤ z ≤ 1
```

This doesn't make quite a difference, since the sample point will still lie in your requested area with high probability.

Now you are left with sampling a point from a [simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex). In the 3d example you get a 2d simplex (triangle) realized in 3d.

How to pick a point uniformly at random was discussed in this [blog post](http://geomblog.blogspot.de/2005/10/sampling-from-simplex.html) (see the comments).

For your problem it would mean that you take $n-1$ random numbers from the interval $(0,1)$, then you add a $0$ and $1$ to get a list of $n+1$ numbers. You sort the list and then you record the differences between two consecutive elements. This gives you a list of $n$ number that will sum up to $1$. Moreover this sampling is uniform. This idea can be found in Donald B. Rubin, [The Bayesian bootstrap](http://emlab.berkeley.edu/pub/users/ruud/e243_f03/pdf/rubin.pdf) Ann. Statist. 9, 1981, 130-134.

For example  ($n=4$)  you have the three random numbers `0.4  0.2 0.1` then you obtain the sorted sequence `0 0.1 0.2 0.4 1` and this gives the differences `0.1 0.1 0.2 0.6`, and by construction these four numbers sum up to 1.

Another approach is the following: first sample from the hypercube (that is you forget about `x+y+z=1`) and then normalize the sample point. The normalization is a projection from the $d$-hypercube to the $d-1$-simplex. It should be intuitively clear that the points at the *center* of the simplex have more "pre-image-points" than at the *outside*. Hence, if you sample uniformly from the hypercube, this wont give you a uniform sampling in the simplex. However, if you sample from the hypercube with an appropriate Exponential Distribution, than this effect cancels out. The Figure gives you an idea how both methods will sample. However, I prefer the "sorting" method due to its simple form. It's also easier to implement.

[image: Example of the 2 sampling methods]

Comment: I guess the naive idea -- draw $n$ numbers from $(0,1)$ and normalise -- is faulty, then.

Comment: I addressed your question in the extended answer.

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting. I was not aware that you could fix it by sampling another distribution (and then normalising). Thanks! Although that leaves the problem of sampling a "suitable" exponential distribution. ;) So I agree, the sorting method is easier even though it seems like magic.

Comment: Are there a simple proof that shows the sorting one gives a uniform distribution? I have only elementary background in probability so the paper is over my head.

Comment: @ChaoXu just observe that there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between $n$ numbers in the simplex and partitions of the interval $(0, 1)$ into $n$ subintervals. the sampling algorithm corresponds to "throwing" $n-1$ random "interval endpoints" on $(0, 1)$. you can try to verify that that's uniform, say by induction and using conditional probability.

Comment: Is there some generalization to non-unit simplex, or even convex polytope?

Comment: @Orient: This might be too much to ask/answer as a comment, but you can surely scale the simplex and the sample point. For a convex polytope you might first split the polytope into simplices, then sample a simplex (weighted by volume) and the sample in the simplex.

Comment: @A.Schulz I beleive I cannot simply deform unit simplex into arbitrary simplex by means of linear transformation only. By doing so I generally loose spatial uniformity of distribution, isn't it?

Comment: @A.Schulz Imagine an equilateral triangle and squeezing one of its sides. The density of points, which are close to the side, is higher, than density of points, which are close to the opposite vertex.

Comment: @A.Schulz Also I am not sure, that triangulation is unavoidable step in case of **convex** polytope.

Comment: @Orient: Please ask you questions in a separate post and dont misuse the comments for this.

Comment: @A.Schulz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800820/random-vectors-uniformely-distributed-into-convex-n-polytope?noredirect=1#comment38496115_24800820

Comment: @A.Schulz I would love to get your opinion on this (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243687/uniform-sampling-from-general-simplex-with-a-twist/)

Comment: There is a paper named "Sampling Uniformly from the Unit Simplex", which proves that the sort based method is incorrect. http://cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/papers/smith+tromble.tr04.pdf

Comment: The answer should also mention that the "normalization" of the sample point is simply a division by its sum, instead of the standard norm.

Comment: Here is a python script to generate data : https://github.com/dilawar/Scripts/blob/master/simplex_generate.py

Answer (score 9):

This is to add to the existing answers.

[Devroye](http://www.eirene.de/Devroye.pdf) is an excellent reference for questions of this sort. Chap.7 gives the algorithms needed to generate uniform order statistics, which the OP is after.

For generating uniform order statistics, sorting $n$ samples of $[0,1]$ will do. This approach takes $O(n \log n)$ time. A quicker way ( available in the book) involves sampling  $n$ random numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ from an $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ pdf. (These are the *spacings* of the uniform pdf). Then, return the values 
$$
(y_i)_{1\leq i\leq n} = \frac{\sum \limits_{1\ldots i} x_j}{\sum \limits_{1\ldots n}  x_j} 
$$
which are automatically sorted, in $O(n)$ time overall. (I'm overlapping with A.Schulz's answer here- just making the computation more explicit).

The same approach can be adapted, via inverse CDF Sampling, to sample any non-uniform pdf over $[0,1]$.  There's also a trick that enables you to sample uniformly over a simplex other than the canonical simplex (say $2x+3y+z = 5$).

Comment: If I follow the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution Then generating random number from exponential distribution involves evaluating logarithm, which can be a bit slow.

Comment: Note sure if its a mistake, but I believe the limits should read $(y_i)_{1\leq i < n}$, so that we get  $n-1$ sorted Uniform  samples [0,1] from $n$ Exponential(1) samples? If not, it seems to me, that the last sample would always equal 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
X[0] = 0
for i = 1 to N-1
    X[i] = uniform(0,1)
X[n] = 1
sort X[0..N]
for i = 1 to N
    Z[i] = X[i] - X[i-1]
return Z[1..N]
```

Here, `uniform(0,1)` returns a real number independently and uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

Comment: This is A. Schulz's answer in code without the explanation, right?

Answer (score 2):

One other possibility is to use the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) using the [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dirichlet.html) module. Essentially, if we set $\alpha=(1,\dots,1)^\top$, then the probability density is effectively uniform on a $n$-dimensional simplex where $n$ is the number of elements in $\alpha$.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import dirichlet
n = 2
size = 1000
alpha = np.ones(n)
samples = dirichlet.rvs(size=size, alpha=alpha)
```

Now, if I plot it using matplotlib, we can see immediately see that it does a good job:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.scatter(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], alpha=0.05)
```

[image: An illustration of sampling from a two-dimensional Dirichlet distribution.]

Answer (score 1):

See [this paper](http://cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/papers/smith+tromble.tr04.pdf): Smith, N. and Tromble, R., *Sampling uniformly from the unit simplex*.

Comment: Please format your answer in a readable way: you're writing for human beings, not the bibtex compiler. Also, if the paper's available online, it's much more efficient for you to provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def rand_simplex(k):
    return tuple(np.random.dirichlet((1,)*k))
```

This will generate one sample at a time.

Comment: Could you please explain the algorithm behind `np.random.dirichlet`?

Comment: It produces samples from a dirichlet distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution.  Intuitively, it is "stick breaking":  Take a stick of unit length and randomly break it resulting in k pieces.  The lengths of those pieces is the random vector.  The parameters are "concentrations" governing the tendencies of each element of the vector to vary between samples.