# Delaunay Triangulation on Convex Polytopes — Uniform Sampling

Tags: computational-geometry, sampling

My goal is to uniformly sample from a convex polytope. I know that for the simpler case, where I have to uniformly sample from a simplex, I can use Bayesian Bootstrap, discussed in these posts:

[Uniform sampling from a simplex](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex)

[Random vectors uniformely distributed into convex n-polytope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800820/random-vectors-uniformely-distributed-into-convex-n-polytope)

Therefore, I'm very interested in this approach. But I don't really know how to use Delaunay Triangulation here. What I have is a linear equation Ax = b and a non-negativity constraint that $x \geq \vec{0}$, and I want to sample x uniformly. Can someone tell me how to do the Delaunay Triangulation here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your simplex closed? Do you know rejection sampling; why is it not applicable here?

Comment: @Raphael Yes, the simplex is closed. I know rejection sampling, but it is very inefficient -- My sampling space has dimension 1000, so rejection sampling will filter out most of the points I sampled.

Answer (score 3):

This is an active area of research. Fortunately, recently there has been a breakthrough due to Vempala and Cousins [1]. They provide a [MATLAB implementation](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~bcousins/volume.html) of their algorithm. If you're interested in the technical details, you can check out some [slides](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vempala/stoc2015-tutorial.html) from a recent workshop.

This algorithm only samples points *approximately* uniformly. Exact uniform sampling, or rather the related volume estimation problem, is known to be hard (under reasonable assumptions) in general. Your convex body isn't general, however – it's a polytope. Nevertheless, the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope) suggest that there is no better algorithm for this special case (they suggest employing general algorithms which are older than Cousins–Vempala).

---

1. [Bypassing KLS: Gaussian Cooling and an $O^*(n^3)$ Volume Algorithm](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.6011) by B. Cousins and S. Vempala (2014, preprint)