# Randomly choose vector b in range such that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 1$

Tags: computational-geometry, linear-algebra

**Given**

- I have a $n$ dimensional $\vec{a}$.
- All elements of $\vec{a}$ are between 0 and a positive number $K$.
- $n$ is about 15 to 20.

**Problem**

I want to randomly and unbiasedly choose a vector $\vec{b}$ such that:

- Elements of $\vec{b}$ are between 0 and 1.
- $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 1$

How to do that?

**Attempt**

I thought about the following:

- Choose $\vec{c}$, a random direction perpendicular to $\vec{b}$.
- Find range of $\theta$ such that $\vec{b} = \frac{\vec{a}}{\lVert \vec{a} \rVert} + \theta\vec{c}$ is within bounds.
- Randoly choose a $\theta$

The problem is that this is not unbiased. Some directions have a larger range of legal $\theta$, and those directions should be chosen more often.

Comment: Is that equivalent to choosing a random point on a simplex with $\vec{a}$ as the normal vector?

Comment: Before going to $n$-dimensional, have you made a detailed analysis on 2-dimensional? How do you define unbiased? Are you able to formalize your requirement, "Some directions have a larger range of legal θ, and those directions should be chosen more often" into probability terms?

Comment: Unbiased: Every $\vec{c}$ that satisfies the conditions in the problem has equal chance to be chosen. "Some directions..." is not a requirement in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Uniformly sampling from a simplex with equation $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 1$, and reject samples out of bounds.

Several answers are posted here for uniform sampling over a simplex: [Uniform sampling from a simplex](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex)

Comment: found another method that doesn't need rejection.